# Remove Specific Elements in Common Header for all the Pages except Home Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js

I modified the homepage header. However, I do not want every other web page, other than the homepage, to look like the homepage header view. Is there a way to remove the `How can we help today?` and search bar header view, and simply portray the header in every page other than the homepage?

[Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97ydj.png)

[Header look in every other web page than the homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qki8D.png)

```
/***** Header *****/
.header {
    max-width: 1160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 71px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

@media (min-width: 1160px) {
    .header {
        padding: 0;
        width: 90%;
    }
}

.logo img {
    max-height: 37px;
}

.user-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

<section class="section hero">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo">
            {{#link 'help_center'}}
            <img src="{{logo_url}}" alt="{{t 'logo'}}">
            {{/link}}
        </div>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <span class="icon-menu"></span>
            <nav class="user-nav" id="user-nav">
                {{link 'new_request' class='submit-a-request'}}
            </nav>
            {{user_info}}
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="hero-inner">
        <h1 style="color:white;">How can we help today?</h1>
        {{search submit=false instant=true class='search search-full'}}
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a class on the homepage ? Most CMS have a "is-front" class applied on the html or body tag. So in the css, you can do

```
.header-inner {display:none}
.is-front header-inner {display:block}
```